# difference in XML feeds something is crashing my android app

Tags: android, xml

I was using a test xml feed for my android app and when I tried my own xml feed now my app crashes.

test feed:

```
http://p-xr.com/xml/
```

my feed:

```
http://www.patriotsar.com/quotes.xml
```

I noticed that when I view the test feed (in a browser) there is no XML formatting or lack of. But when I view the test feed it looks like html.

I am grabbing the XML using:

```
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://www.patriotsar.com/quotes.xml");
```

Comment: What does your LogCat say, What is the error?

Answer (score 0):

[Your XML](http://www.patriotsar.com/quotes.xml) has 3 extra tags:

```
 <html>
  <head/>
      <body>
      <sfdocready id="sfDocReady"/>
     </body>
 </html>
```

Where as the [test XML](http://p-xr.com/xml/) does not.

You can view the text XML properly by going to the web address then right clicking on the page and pressing 'View Source' (Google Chrome)

Comment: Actually I was using firebug and saw the html headers in firefox. so i added those shortly after this post when I did not get a response. Originally I just viewed the test pages source and copied the code from the test page that is what I put in my xml on my server.